# Calculating the distribution....

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure

Let us consider the experiment of choosing at random a chord of the circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ given parametrically by $(\cos 2\pi t,\sin 2\pi t )$, $0 \leq t < 1$.  Let $\Omega$ be the unit square $[0,1)^2$. Let $\mathcal{A}$ denote the borel fied of subsets of $\Omega$ and let $P$ be the uniform distribution on $\Omega$.  Let $\Psi$ be the space of chords of the given circle and let $\mathcal{B}$ denote the Borel field of subsets of $\Psi$ with $\Psi$ being regarded as a subspace of the metric space of all compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$  (with the Hausdorff metric).

For $w=(w_1,w_2)\in \Omega$, let $X_1(w)$ denote the line segment having endpoints $(\cos 2\pi w_1,\sin 2\pi  w_1)$ and $(\cos 2\pi w_2,\sin 2\pi w_2 )$. Notice that $X_1(w)$ is a chord of the circle of interest and $X_1$ is a random set that is, a set-valued random variable.

Another interpretation of ´at random´, using the same spaces $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ and $(\Psi,\mathcal{B})$. Let $X_2$ be the chord that both passes through the point whose polar coordinates are $(2w_1-1,\pi w_2)$ and is perpendicular to the line segment from the origin to that point. In case $w_1=1/2$ this line segment consists of a single point, but we can still define its direction by $\pi w_2$.

With the interpretation $X_1$ and $X_2$, what definition of ´chord´ is being implicitly used. For $i=1,2$ let $Q_i$ denote the distribution of $X_i$, for each $i$.

My question is How can I calculate $Q_i(C)$ where $C$ is the set of chords that intersect both the positive vertical axis and the negative horizontal axis. Could someone help me, please?

Thanks for your time and help. (some hints please!)

Comment: Someone could help me to understand how calculate the distribution of these cases?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of a chord is the same in both, the definition of 'choosing a chord at random' (the distribution) is different.

For a problem like this, I'm not so sure if you can (easily) compute the entire distribution. Its easier to calculate $Q_i( C)$ "by hand".
I'll sketch out the first and you can then hopefully figure out the second. For a chord $AB$ with defing points $A=A(w_1)=(A_1(w_1),A_2(w_1))$, and $B=B(w_2)$ to intersect the $x$-axis, we need the signs of the second coordinates of the two points two be different. Similarly for the first coordinate. Hence we need $A_1B_1 ≤ 0$ and $A_2B_2 ≤ 0$. You just need to find the range of $w_1$ and $w_2$ where these hold, and the product of the length of the ranges, since they are independent and uniform on $[0,1)$, is the answer.